# How to reload a CollectionView after deleting a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView that displays cells populated from an online web application that, when clicked on, give the option of deleting from that web application.

I use a completion handler to only reload the data if the api call was successful and the web application no longer has that cell stored. However reloadData() doesn't display one less cell when called on. I've tried layoutIfNeeded(), setNeedsDisplay() and collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout().

None of them do anything and the cell that was delete always remains there.. 
**But if I use the navigation controller to move back and then go forward to the view with the CollectionView again, it is gone.** Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var inviteCollectionView: UICollectionView
 func declineInvite(id: Int)
{
    requestModel.deleteRequest(id: id, completion: { success in
        if(success)
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("This happens")



                    self.inviteCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

                    self.inviteCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self.inviteCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }

        }
        else{
            print("Failed deleting group")
        }

    })
}
```

**Updated with numberOfItemsInSection:**

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return requestTuples.count
}
```

And requestTuples is from

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    (requestModel.getRequests()

        {(returnValue)
            in self.requestTuples = (returnValue)

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your delete request is that you don't remove the item from the array `requestTuples` with the specified id , you only reload the collectionView

```
func declineInvite(id: Int) {
    requestModel.deleteRequest(id: id, completion: { success in
        if(success) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {  
                self.requestTuples.remove(at:id)
                self.inviteCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed deleting group")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Is `id` really the index in the array or is it some key?

Comment: @rmaddy It's the index of the item to be deleted

Comment: You don't know that. You are making an assumption. Nothing in the OP's code indicates that `id` is simply the index into the array.

Comment: look to the func parameters  , he first delete it from the server and after a successful remote delete , local index should be deleted

Comment: I'm fully aware of what is being done and what needs to be done. But none of that means that `id` is simply an array index. Given its name and give how it is used to delete the remote data, it is probably some unique identifier of the data that has nothing to do with the local index of the `requestTuples` array. In the end it *might* match the index, but the point of my original comment is to ask the OP if that is actually the case.

Comment: So this answer worked for me thank you. However for id instead of using id i used indexPath.row from my collectionView!

Comment: @rmaddy , yep I got it , for sure i concluded that and thought that the delete may be from didSelect , or some other delete method , so id according to OP current comment = indexPath.row , but we both agree that not deleting the local data is the main reason of the problem

Answer (score 0):

To avoid reloading the whole collection (which is very inefficient) is better to use the deleteItems function (always after updating your array with the source of course!)

```
func deleteItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618060-deleteitems